# Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, xcode4.5

the final line always throw a exception:"invalid key in JSON dictionary".
I cant figure out why. I can print the "msg" dictionary.

```
NSDictionary* header = @{
@(udpVersion) : @"ver",
@(self.dataType) : @"type",
@(self.ack) : @"ack",
[WBUserMng sharedClient].getUserId : @"src",
};

NSDictionary* msg = @{
header:@"head",
self.payload:@"data",
};

NSError* error = nil;
return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:msg options:kNilOptions error:&error]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have the wrong order of *key* and *value* in the new Objective C syntax for dictionary literals. It should probably be

```
NSDictionary* msg = @{
    @"head" : header,
    @"data" : self.payload
};
```

and the same for the `header` dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

First time i see @{} or @(self.dataType) directive. I dunno how u can compile it.
Give us more hint.

```
NSDictionary* dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"a" forKey: @"b"];

[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: dic options: NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error: nil];
```

or

```
NSString* jsonString =  @"{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"foo2\": \"bar2\"}";
// no commat one the last JSON line
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: jsonString options: NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error: nil];
```

Comment: new feature brought by xcode 4.5. I really compile this correctly.  So  I dont think this will be a problem....

Comment: ok, i've just discovered this new feature. What are self.dataType / self.ack signature? By the way if you get a null from [WBUserMng sharedClient].getUserId or whatever objet from, an exception will be thrown. You should always get a non-nil key object